# Bug Odoo AccessError (Тип документа: res.users, Операция: read) multicompany

Tags: access, odoo

Я использую odoo 8.0, с опцией холдинг.

Странное поведение:
1. Создайте нового пользователя 
2. В качестве компании, в которой он работает, я указываю компанию, которая была создана при установке odoo (Установлена у Администратора).

3. Я назначаю ему права Sale \ Manager. После этого пользователь может создать новых партнеров.

Все нормально.

Я создаю новую компанию и устанавливаю ее для пользователя.

Я получаю сообщение об ошибке:

AccessError: ('AccessError', u 'Запрошенная операция не может быть выполнена из-за ограничений безопасности.) Обратитесь к своему системному администратору. \ N \ n (Тип документа: res.users, Операция: read) ')

Я действительно пересмотрел права доступа к res_company, res_users, res_partner, а также правилам доступа, но не смог найти причину.

После этого я беру трассировку уровня SQL. Есть в приложении.

Если пользователю установить вновь созданную компанию, то ошибка пропадает при работе с новой компанией, но возникает  у пользователей, первой компании.

https://yadi.sk/d/E6X7CFrt3HgGMd

```
2017-05-04 22:30:42,961 3342 ERROR db1 openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 544, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 581, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 317, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 314, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 810, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 410, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 944, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/geoengine_geoname_geocoder/res_partner.py", line 126, in create
    res = super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py", line 577, in create
    partner = super(res_partner, self).create(vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 381, in create
    thread_id = super(mail_thread, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4104, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4295, in _create
    result += self._columns[field].set(cr, self, id_new, field, vals[field], user, rel_context) or []
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1485, in set
    self._fnct_inv(obj, cr, user, id, name, value, self._fnct_inv_arg, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 282, in _set_followers
    self.message_subscribe(cr, uid, [id], list(new-old), context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 1799, in message_subscribe
    }, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/mail_followers.py", line 67, in create
    record = super(mail_followers, self).create(vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4104, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4320, in _create
    recs.recompute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 5773, in recompute
    name: rec[name] for name in names
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 5773, in <dictcomp>
    name: rec[name] for name in names
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 5657, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/fields.py", line 841, in __get__
    return record._cache[self]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 6057, in __getitem__
    return value.get() if isinstance(value, SpecialValue) else value
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/fields.py", line 56, in get
    raise self.exception
AccessError: ('AccessError', u'The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: res.users, Operation: read)')
```

Работа остановилась, нужна помощь!

Comment: На текущий момент поиски привели к созданию запроса https://github.com/OCA/geospatial/issues/139. Есть идеи как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Bug.

```
    diff -u res_partner.py.bug res_partner.py
--- res_partner.py.bug  2017-05-05 03:29:50.631889870 +0300
+++ res_partner.py      2017-05-08 21:47:21.356468826 +0300
@@ -90,9 +90,7 @@
         If one of those parameters is not set then reset the partner's
         geo_point and do not recompute it
         """
-        if not self.partner_latitude or not self.partner_longitude:
-            self.geo_point = False
-        else:
+        if self.partner_latitude and self.partner_longitude:
             self.geo_point = geo_fields.GeoPoint.from_latlon(
                 self.env.cr, self.partner_latitude, self.partner_longitude)
```